# How can I observe the effects of the entanglement?

Tags: entanglement

A possibly to ignorant question. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Quantum_entanglement) I read:

> For example, if she measures a $|0\rangle$,Bob must measure the same, as $|00\rangle$
> is the only state where Alice's qubit is a $|0\rangle$

In the Quantum composer, with the "Bell State ZZ-Measurement" code, `q0` and `q1` are entagled but, changing the visualization seed (now at 6162), they have distinct measures.

Is this because 'higher correlation' doesn't mean 'identical values' or am I misinterpreting the basic elements?
Many thanks.

[image: Bell State ZZ-Measurement]

Comment: Correlation between measurement outcomes does not detect entanglement (you might choose to read about Bertlmann's socks!). If you actually want to observe the effect of entanglement, and know it's due to entanglement, you need to do quite a bit more such as measuring a Bell inequality.

Comment: are you asking the general question written in the title, or about the specific case in the body of the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to observe verifiable entanglement between two parties $A$ and $B$ is to have them play the [CHSH game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nh-pjxnM4I). In this game, each player receives an input bit $x$ (resp. $y$) from a referee (also called the verifier), and each player must respond with an output bit $a$ (resp. $b$) to the referee.

Once the game begins, the parties cannot communicate and do not know the inputs given to the other player. The parties win if their outputs satisfy the predicate $a\oplus b=x\cdot y$, or in words, the XOR of their outputs is equal to the AND of their inputs.

One can show that the probability of $A$ and $B$ winning without entanglement between them is at best [$3/4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_refereed_game#CHSH_Refereed_Game). But if the parties share genuine entanglement, then there is a strategy that wins with probability $\cos^2(\pi/8)\approx 0.85$. Moreover, if they do win with this probability (the game may need to be played over and over to see this), then it can be shown that the parties must be employing genuine quantum correlations (i.e. entanglement).

Comment: I'm not sure why you need rigidity of the CHSH game to rule out classical strategies. Surely the fact that any non-entangled strategy has a winning probability of at most $3/4$ is sufficient (as long as you have enough statistics).

Comment: Ah right, rigidity is only needed in the non-ideal case. I will just remove that part of the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "needed in the non-ideal case"? For detecting entanglement rigidity (self-testing) is never needed as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yes, you are right about detection, rigidity is not needed. But to clarify, by "the non-ideal case" I mean when players win with probability at least $\omega-\epsilon$ where $\omega$ is the optimal value and $\epsilon>0$. In this case, the rigidity of CHSH says that their shared state is still "close" to being maximally entangled. In particular, it's $O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$ away from the maximally entangled state in norm.

Comment: Many thanks @Condo, CHSH game helped me to understand better. I also went trough this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUQYSy6C1aA).
I understand that probability is at the heart of the question but find it difficult to master it. Recalling the example above. I suppose that this sentence is ill but I do not know how to get out of it: if two qubits are entangled and they are measured in the same basis the two measures will always be identical?

Comment: Hi @RobertoScotti the state $\tfrac{|01\rangle+|10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ is entangled and if either Alice or Bob measure their qubit in the $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ basis they will always get different outcomes.